# How to reattach faux stones to wall?

Tags: walls, exterior, stone

I have a faux stone facade on the outside of my house:

[image]

Some of the pieces have come off. This one shows the part that was attached and it looks like some type of cement had previously been used to attach it:

[image]

These 2 images try to show the material that these faux stones are made of:

[image]

[image]

I've tried reattaching these stones with epoxy and also with Gorilla Glue spray but neither of these have worked very well. The faux stone appears to be somewhat absorbent and I think this might be impacting the result.

What is the best material to use to reattach these?

Comment: Here, people would tend to use PL construction adhesive. As long as this is just cosmetic and not meant to keep water off from the wall

Comment: Either answer below will work, including the comment above, but you will need to temporarily support the stone for a day while either one sets up. A thick application of thinset (mortar for tile)  will not simply hold the weight of the stone unless another stone is under it already. It does not look like you have that. You will need to add something under it and perhaps something to lean against it so It does not roll off the temporary support.

Answer (score 3):

I've used Liquid Nails Fuse It adhesive for many outdoor, masonry projects like securing paver planters. It works best when you apply it heavily to both surfaces and then fit them together. Support the stones in place until the adhesive cures. I'm not affiliated with Liquid Nails in any way.

Clean off all the old stuff used to previously attach the stones.

Answer (score 3):

One uses tile mortar for tiles.

In your case you can look at the stones as tiles.

Apply tile mortar to the tile then flip it and push against the wall. Hold in place for a short wile.

Since the surface is rough, be generous with mortar.